# ¿Por qué es diminutivo "mantequilla"?

Tags: vocabulario, comida, diminutivos

Que la palabra *mantequilla* viene de *manteca* está más que claro. Las dos son grasas animales. La primera se elabora a base de la leche bovina y contiene sólidos lácteos. La segunda es de gordura corporeal, sea de vaca o de chancho. Una no se produce de la otra y ni es más pequeña.

¿Por qué se emplea el diminutivo para nombrar *mantequilla*?

[image]

Comment: El diminutivo sirve para varias cosas, no sólo para cosas pequeñas.  También sirve para indicar cierta actitud.  "¿Quieres aguïta?" indica que crees que el agua le va a quedar bien a la persona, y que la estás ofreciendo con atentividad, e incluso, cariño.  La mantequilla es fina.  Finita.

Comment: @aparente001 no son iguales, la mantequilla y la manteca ofrecida cariñosamente. quizás la parte láctea constituye el cariño.

Comment: En Argentina (y varios otros países, creo) se usa exclusivamente la palabra "manteca" para lo que los españoles llaman "mantequilla" (derivado de la leche).

Comment: @AaronBrick - Mucha gente considera la mantequilla más fina que la manteca.  Lo que tienen en común es que ambas son grasas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En español, **manteca** sí puede referirse a la crema que se obtiene de la leche de vaca (o similar):

> **[manteca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OGdz85i)**
>
> 1. f. Producto obtenido por el batido, amasado y posterior maduración de la crema extraída de la leche de vaca o de otros animales. *Manteca de vaca, de oveja*.

Y, en este sentido, mantequilla se refiere especificamente a la manteca de leche de vaca:

> **[mantequilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OHSwRer)**
>
> 1. f. **Manteca** de la leche de vaca.
> 2. f. Producto obtenido de la leche o de la crema por agitación o por batimiento, ya usando máquinas a propósito, ya mazando la leche en odres.

En cualquier caso, el sufijo **-illa** no siempre forma un diminutivo en sentido literal. La propia definición del DLE lo explica:

> **[-illo, lla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KywyhW2)**
>
> 1. suf. Tiene valor diminutivo o afectivo. *Arbolillo, librillo, guapillo, mentirosilla.* **Aunque no todos los sustantivos formados con este sufijo tienen auténtico valor diminutivo, suelen aproximarse a él**: p. ej., *organillo* con relación a *órgano*; *molinillo* con relación a *molino*; *camilla* con relación a *cama*, etc. A veces, toma las formas -ecillo, -ececillo, -cillo. *Panecillo, piececillo, amorcillo.*

El caso de *mantequilla* y *manteca*, en su uso más general, entraría en la parte que he resaltado en negrita: indica simplemente que la primera se ha nombrado en relación a la segunda, pues tienen el mismo origen y se usa(ba)n más o menos para lo mismo, siendo la diferencia que la mantequilla es más suave y blanda.

Comment: Gracias. Yo pensaba que lo afectivo era un aspecto resultante del diminutivo, no un par de el, con respeto a este sufijillo.